# Is a Bessel function larger than all other Bessel functions when evaluated at its first maximum?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, special-functions

Let $\mathcal{J}_{n+1/2}$ be the Bessel function of order $n+1/2$. Let $j'_{n+1/2,1}$ denote the first zero of its derivative, which is also the location of the first maximum of $\mathcal{J}_{n+1/2}$.

---

My question: Given a non-negative integer $n$, is it true that $|\mathcal{J}_{m+1/2}(j'_{n+1/2,1})|<|\mathcal{J}_{n+1/2}(j'_{n+1/2,1})|$ holds for all non-negative integers $m\neq n$?

---

EDIT: The answer is yes and the proof can be found in the appendix of the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07306 Thanks for the helpful comment @Jung Wen Chen!

Comment: Have you written up the proof somewhere? I would like to read it.

Comment: Yes, see the edit

Comment: Jung Wen Chen isn't my name. I think MO is nicer if answers are answers judged for what they are worth without wondering whether the author is a graduate student or a tenured faculty or a field medalist, as it leads to automatically favouring answers from annointed mathematicians. 

If you really want to say something in your paper, a general acknowledgement to fruitful discussions on mathoverflow  for example would be more fair to the process which lead to the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We suppose $0<m<n$. It is known, from Landau's paper quoted above that
$
n\to n^{1/3}J_n(x_n)
$
increases (to some universal constant $b$). Thus
$$
J_n(x_n)>\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{1/3}J_m(x_m)>\left(\frac{m}{x_n}\right)^{1/3}J_m(x_m).
$$
It is also known that for $x>n$,
$
x\to \sqrt{x^2-n^2}((J_n(x))^2+(Y_n(x))^2) 
$
increases to $2/\pi$. Therefore, as $x_n>n>m$
$$
|J_m(x_n)|^2\leq \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n^2 -m^2}}.
$$
Therefore, the inequality holds at least for all $n,m$ such that
$$
\frac{2}{\pi m^{2/3}(J_m(x_m))^2}<\sqrt{x_n^{2} -m^{2}} \frac{1}{x_n^{2/3}},
$$ 
and the left hand-side is between $1.39$ and $1.89$. 
If we write $$m=\frac{x_n}{1+\lambda x_n^{-2/3}}$$ we find that this inequality holds for all $x_n\geq40$, and $\lambda>11/10$ for example. The asymptotic of $x_n$ is quite well known, and it is precisely of that sort of magnitude, $x_n=n+\beta n^{1/3}+O(1)$. So, refining the argument and using $n$ instead of $x_n$, you would be very close. For $m=n-1$, you get 
$$
\frac{2}{\pi m^{2/3}(J_m(x_m))^2}<\sqrt{\beta^2 n^{2/3} +2\beta n^{4/3}+2n-1} \frac{1}{n^{2/3}},
$$ 
Asymptotically, this is not enough, because $\beta\approx 0.8$ and $\sqrt{1.6}=1.26<1.39$, but that does limit the range of $m$ to investigate, to $m\geq n- n^{1/3}/5$, so you are only have to consider the case when $J_m(x_n)>0$, $J_m^\prime(x_n)<0$, as the first root is further away ($m+ 1.8m^{1/3}$).

Comment: thank you for this answer. However, I am interested in an argument that circumvents the (well-studied) asymptotics of Bessel functions, because I want to prove the claim for all m.

Comment: Also, I don't see how you arrive at the second line. I suspect it should have J_n(x_n)^2 on the right-hand side.

Comment: Finally, I want to remind you that the question asks about Bessel functions of _half_-integer order. While Landau's result holds for arbitrary orders, I don't know if this is also true for the limiting result for the modulus that you use.

Comment: @MLemm I am note sure what you mean by second line. If you mean second inequality, it is true for all $\nu\geq\frac{1}{2}$: $|H^{(1)}_{\nu}(x)|^2\sqrt{x^2-\nu^2}$ is increasing to its limit (for $x>\nu$), $2/\pi$. Page 447, 13.74 Watson's book.
I used no asymptotic result which is not true for all $m$. The bound $x_{\nu}>\nu+0.8\nu^{1/3}$ is true for all $n>1$.Everything is for all $m$, of the form integer plus a half or not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have a reference for $x_\nu>\nu +0.8 \nu^{1/3}$? I can only find an old paper by Gatteschi & Laforgia, which adresses uniform lower bounds on $x_\nu$, but does not quite yield this for all $\nu > 1$.

Comment: Also, I can prove the full statement now. Can you provide me with your real name, so that I can acknowledge your input properly?

Comment: @MLemm The DLMF is a good reference. 10.21(iv) says that $j^\prime_{\nu,1}/{\nu}$ is a decreasing function of $\nu$, so you just need a asymptotic bound below, and 10.21.40 gives it for you. In terms of acknowledgement, accepting my answer is more than enough ;)

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. A decreasing function may still be much lower than its asymptotics for small arguments.

Comment: @MLemm you are right. On the other hand, the asymptotic expansion 10.21.40 is convergent, taking it with 3 terms, and checking would do it I guess. Olver gives error bounds in his 1973 book.